# How to create a protected RSS feed

Tags: feeds

We are planning to provide an RSS feed (from a Drupal site) to someone who is going to display it on their site. Is there a way to limit access to only this specific site or maybe provide an embed code they can use to display the feed on their site?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Views to provide it then you can limit it by role/ permission (which will tie your user to a [REST login process](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/javascript-and-drupal-8-restful-web-services)), else the [Views RSS Feed Authentication](https://www.drupal.org/project/vrssfa) module allows you to utilise basic auth or oauth.

There are plenty of options, but what you do will depend on how you intend to implement the feed.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions Pobtastic. While we are updating to D8, we are still in D7 now. Any modules that will work with a D7 site?

Also, can you say a little more about how we might implement the feed? We have not provided a feed to a specific site in the past.

Comment: As I say, there are various methods of doing it - it really depends on the requirements of the site? At the very simplest, you could just use CORS? There is a module, but you could also achieve it with a few lines in your htaccess or apache config. If I were you, I'd stick with implementing it in Views - but it really depends on your developers, and how confident they feel about updating to D8?